# Counting words and specific characters in a file with switch statements

Tags: java

Alright, so basically what I have to do here is read a file containing words. Some of these words have special characters such as quotes, periods, hyphens etc at the beginning and end. I have to count all of the words in the file, count how many special characters there are, remove them, and print out each word on a seperate line without the special characters.

So now that we have the purpose out of the way, i'd like to explain my thought process with the coding I have below. So in the beginning I was thinking of how to use switch statements to remove specific characters, and since I think that you can only use numbers in switch statements I thought using the decimal number for a character from the ascii table would be the best way to go. So I did that, and it prints out all of the words just as they should be. However, when counting up all of the special characters it gets it completely wrong, only counting a fraction of the total amount. I am just at a loss as to why exactly it is doing this, so any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;   

public class FileWords
{
public static void main( String [] args ) throws IOException
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a file name: ");
    File file = new File(scan.next() );

    Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(file);
    String fileContent;
    int wordNum = 0, quote = 0, dubQuote = 0, semi = 0, colon = 0, period = 0, comma = 0, hyphen = 0, exclamation = 0, dollar = 0,  question = 0, words = 0;

    do
    {
        fileContent = scanFile.next();  
        wordNum = fileContent.length();     

        switch ( (fileContent.charAt(0)) )
        {
            case 34: 
            dubQuote ++;
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( 1 , wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" ") );
            break;

            case 36: 
            dollar++;
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( 1 , wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" ") );
            break;

            case 39:
            quote++;
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( 1 , wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" ") );
            break;

            case 46:    
            period++;
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( 1 , wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" ") );  
            break;

            default:
            break;  
        }               

        wordNum = fileContent.length();

        switch ( fileContent.charAt(wordNum - 1) )
        {
            case 33: 
            exclamation++;
            words++;
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( 0 , wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" ") );
            break;

            case 34: 
            dubQuote ++;
            words++;
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( 0 , wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" ") );
            break;

            case 39: 
            quote++;
            words++;
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( 0 , wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" ") );
            break;

            case 44: 
            comma++;
            words++;
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( 0 , wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" ") );
            break;

            case 45: 
            hyphen++;
            words++;
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( 0 , wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" ") );
            break;

            case 46: 
            period++;
            words++;
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( 0 , wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" ") );
            break;

            case 58: 
            colon++;
            words++;
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( 0 , wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" ") );
            break;

            case 59: 
            semi++;
            words++;
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( 0 , wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" ") );
            break;

            case 63: 
            question++;
            words++;
            fileContent = fileContent.substring( 0 , wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" ") );
            break;

            default:
            words++;
            break;
        }


        System.out.println(fileContent);

    } // end of do
    while (scanFile.hasNext());

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Double Quotes:       " + dubQuote);
    System.out.println("Single Quotes:       " + quote);
    System.out.println("Semi-Colons:         " + semi);
    System.out.println("Colons:              " + colon);
    System.out.println("Periods:             " + period);
    System.out.println("Commas:              " + comma);
    System.out.println("Hyphens:             " + hyphen);
    System.out.println("Exclamation Points:  " + exclamation);
    System.out.println("Question Marks:      " + question);
    System.out.println("Dollar Signs:        " + dollar);
    System.out.println("Words Found:         " + words);

}
}
```

Comment: Instead of using numbers, try using the actual character surrounded by single quotes, such as `'$'`.

Comment: FYI, [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/) supports [Strings in switch statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)

Comment: Either way it doesn't change anything, I don't think thats the problem. I think it has something to do with the way its structured but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @user1645307 Understood, just speaking to your point that "that you can only use numbers in switch statements" for the benefit of other readers.

Comment: For this specific assignment I am able to assume that. I don't mean in general

Comment: A small, test

"of" some 'things.



Now the way it comes out is correct, printing A small test of some thing and having each word on a seperate line. That's perfect. But when we get to the counting part it has 1 single quote, 1 double quote, and a comma. It should have 1 more double quote but it isn't counting.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way to do this would be to simply use an array to go through each character and use the Character.isLetter() method. If the character is a letter add it to the string, if not check if its a space or a new line. If its a space or newline print the string and keep going else skip that character, its not a letter or something separating two words. This will also check for all possible special characters not just the ones you are currently looking at.

Comment: I would, but I am unable to use arrays or for loops. So I kinda have to go the complicated way. Sorry for not stating it in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a clue, the following expression:

```
fileContent.substring(1, wordNum + fileContent.indexOf(" "))
```

Seems to be problematic. Consider what happens when you have a file with the following contents:

> "a"

The output is:

```
Double Quotes:       1
Single Quotes:       0
Semi-Colons:         0
Colons:              0
Periods:             0
Commas:              0
Hyphens:             0
Exclamation Points:  0
Question Marks:      0
Dollar Signs:        0
Words Found:         1
```

Thus, the quotes are mis-counted. The logic error can be corrected as follows:

```
switch ((fileContent.charAt(0))) {                                            
case 34:                                                                      
    dubQuote++;                                                               
    fileContent = fileContent.substring(1, wordNum);                          
    break;                                                                    

case 36:                                                                      
    dollar++;                                                                 
    fileContent = fileContent.substring(1, wordNum);                          
    break;                                                                    

case 39:                                                                      
    quote++;                                                                  
    fileContent = fileContent.substring(1, wordNum);                          
    break;                                                                    

case 46:                                                                      
    period++;                                                                 
    fileContent = fileContent.substring(1, wordNum);                          
    break;                                                                    

default:                                                                      
    break;                                                                    
}                                                                             

wordNum = fileContent.length() - 1;                                           

switch (fileContent.charAt(wordNum)) {                                        
case 33:                                                                      
    exclamation++;                                                            
    words++;                                                                  
    fileContent = fileContent.substring(0, wordNum);                          
    break;                                                                    

case 34:                                                                      
    dubQuote++;                                                               
    words++;                                                                  
    fileContent = fileContent.substring(0, wordNum);                          
    break;                                                                    

case 39:                                                                      
    quote++;                                                                  
    words++;                                                                  
    fileContent = fileContent.substring(0, wordNum);                          
    break;                                                                    

case 44:                                                                      
    comma++;                                                                  
    words++;                                                                  
    fileContent = fileContent.substring(0, wordNum);                          
    break;                                                                    

case 45:                                                                      
    hyphen++;                                                                 
    words++;                                                                  
    fileContent = fileContent.substring(0, wordNum);                          
    break;                                                                    

case 46:                                                                      
    period++;                                                                 
    words++;                                                                  
    fileContent = fileContent.substring(0, wordNum);                          
    break;                                                                    

case 58:                                                                      
    colon++;                                                                  
    words++;                                                                  
    fileContent = fileContent.substring(0, wordNum);                          
    break;                                                                    

case 59:                                                                      
    semi++;                                                                   
    words++;                                                                  
    fileContent = fileContent.substring(0, wordNum);                          
    break;                                                                    

case 63:                                                                      
    question++;                                                               
    words++;                                                                  
    fileContent = fileContent.substring(0, wordNum);                          
    break;                                                                    

default:                                                                      
    words++;                                                                  
    break;                                                                    
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to fix this? I've been having a discussion with a guy in the comments and just came to this but I'm not sure how to make it count the quote at the end of the word.

Comment: Nevermind actually, the problem was that in the first switch statement I assigned fileContent a new value that was incorrect. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I figured it out. The problem was that in the first switch statement I assigned fileContent an incorrect value. All i had to do was remove the + fileContent.indexOf(" ") and I was golden.

Comment: It's not just the `+ fileContent.indexOf(" ")`, it's also the second switch. Review my answer.